# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.Datatype nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Datatype nvarchar but for using between I need to change it to date datatype, but it is showing error.

This is my Current TimeStamp : 2017-02-03 19:12:37.503

```
select PartNo,Convert(date,WODate,103) 
from   Inspection 
where  Convert(date,WODate,103) between Convert(date,'03-01-2017',103) 
       and Convert(date,'05-01-2017',103)
```

Comment: You mention one format in your question but your code uses a different one. What *is* the the actual format? What is the type of `WODate` and what does it contain?

Comment: I'd suggest you to keep the format yyyy-MM-dd, personal experience.

Comment: BTW you don't need to convert the literals. Just use unseparated date literals, ie `BETWEEN '20170103' and '20170105')`. The unseparated date literal is unambiguous.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete only the unseparated or full ISO8601 format are unambiguous. All other are subject to localization issues

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand - 2009-10-16](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: @VipinG if `WODate` is a text field you have a serious bug. You should use the *correct* type for each kind of data. Dates should be stored using date types, not strings. If `WODate` was a `date` you could simply write `WODate between '20`70103' and ...`. The conversion also prevents the query optimizer from using indexes, resulting in full table scans

Answer (score 0):

You should, if possible, change the datatype of the column to DateTime (or just Date, if that's all you need).
Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) to find out why.

If that's not possible, then you should at least use the correct style when converting to date:

```
select PartNo, Convert(date,WODate,121) 
from   Inspection 
where  Convert(date,WODate,120) <= date,'2017-01-03' 
and    Convert(date,WODate,120) <= '2017-01-05'
```

**Notes:**

1. The 103 style is for string with the folowing format: `dd/MM/yyyy`.
   For the format you use in your strings (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) you need to use the 121 style.
2. When using strings to represent dates in sql server, it's best to use the format `'yyyyMMdd'`. Almost as good is `'yyyy-MM-dd'`. If you want to also include time, use `'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'` (note that M stands for monthes while m stands for minutes, also don't forget to separate the date and time porsions with the capital T).

You can read all about it in the [MSDN page on cast and convert.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: change the datatype of the column to DateTime = I tried to Alter It But it gives the Same error

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have a datetime in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm and you are trying to convert it with a 103 format, which is dd/mm/yyyy. Your other hard coded dates follow that format, but needn't when you can use the literal format without a convert. I would suggest you use the following:

```
select PartNo, WODate
from   Inspection 
where  Convert(date,WODate,121) between '20170103'
       and '05-01-20170105'
```

The following resource has the formats for reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp